# replace multiple substrings of value from table wit hsql

Tags: sql, string, loops, replace, varchar

I have the following tables (all values are varchar):

table1:

| name | value |
| --- | --- |
| one | a,b,c |
| two | a,c,d |
| three | b,c,d |

table2:

| value | remove |
| --- | --- |
| a | true |
| b | true |
| c | false |
| d | false |

I now need to remove from table1.value all values with are marked in table2 as remove. So that I get this as a result. (the duplicate comma separators will be removed later)

| name | value |
| --- | --- |
| one | ,,c |
| two | ,c,d |
| three | ,c,d |

I already know the REPLACE function in SQL, but with this I could only replace one item at a time, but there are posibly hundreds of them, so I need to automate this step.

is there any posibility to do something like this in SQL:

```
for (SELECT value FROM table2 WHERE remove = 'true') AS val
{
UPDATE table1 SET value = REPLACE(value, val, '')
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Storing and manipulating CSV data in this way is bad practice.  Please get each CSV value onto a separate row.

Comment: You database model is not even at the 1NF level. You should strongly consider improving the design at least to 3NF.

Comment: you need to tag your database

Comment: Seems like it's HyperSQL.

Comment: i know that this datamodel is reeeaaally bad, but i have to deal with it

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: it is a Postgres DB